# How to prevent the message: Not enough memory to display a cell

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, warning-messages, gui-construction, memory

While running a single-cell GUI application that repeatedly changes and refreshes its content I got this message: There was not enough memory to display a cell...  I found in [this old MathGroup thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2002/Nov/msg00114.html) some hints to develop a workaround in Windows.  I would like to know if nowadays a programmatic solution to this problem can be created such such that the problem can be diagnosing and fixed before it hits.  Just in case, I have more than enough "Memory Available" as I can see from `SystemInformation["Machine"]`.

Comment: Can you include an example that triggers this error?

Comment: Indeed one of my customers sent me a screenshot where the application I created triggered the message after a couple of hours of continuous use. So, it is almost impossible for me to replicate the problem in my computer.